General relativity
I was reading a physic text, and I don’t understand how to transform their non rigorous argument. The part where I don’t get it is when they write $d\theta=d\phi=0$. It means nothing as $d\theta$ and $d\phi$ are non trivial linear forms (for example, $d\theta:(t,r,\theta,\phi)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R_{+}^*\times[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi[\mapsto\left((a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb R^4\mapsto c \in\mathbb R\right)\in(\mathbb R^4)^*$).
Can anyone translate it in maths terms?
EDIT : It turns out that I was mistaken on the definition of some operation (see my answer below), and that the derivation below is mathematically correct through the theory of manifolds. Still, I let this mistake here, in case anyone is equally mistaken.


They are following an specific path, "radial null geodesic" along which those are zero. Where the "radial" in the name refers to those angles, $\theta$ and $\phi$, not changing.

@ameg, I understand that those angles do not vary, but $d\theta$ for example, does not represent a small variation of $\theta$, it’s the mathematical object described above. What you are saying is the same “physical” manipulation that I have a hard time translating in maths terms… is it clearer ?

"does not represent a small variation of $\theta$" I don't know what you are saying. $d\theta=d\phi=0$ is a system of differential equations. They are looking at a set of points at which these are satisfied. That's all. Also, you do not need to think in coordinates $(a,b,c,d)$. You could choose coordinates $(\theta, \phi, r, t)$, in which it is simpler to interpret $d\theta=0$ and $d\phi=0$.

@ameg I think you are making a confusion here, seeing $\theta$ as a function of some parameter (let’s call it $\sigma$) and thinking that $d\theta$ is the differential of the function $\theta:\sigma\mapsto\theta(\sigma)$ whereas in the expression above, $d\theta$ is the function described in my post.

You should start with this assumption "the one confused is you". After all, you are the one asking.

No, $\theta$ is exactly a function of some parameter $\sigma$. That what the geodesic is for.

@Trebor I am not sure I get you. Of course, when considering a trajectory on a null geodesic, theta is a function of a parameter of the geodesic $\theta$, but the term $d\theta$ in the equation (5.1) isn’t the differential of this function of theta, but just a notation designing the function in my post. No ?

They are the differential. What else is going to be? If your text is at a point where they somehow got to that equation, but the $d\theta$ and $d\phi$ are appeared there as renaming some unknown expression, then your question should be about what happened in pages before the one quoted. On the other hand, if for example, this just came from the same equation in Cartesian coordinates, and they changed variables to spherical, then it is just chain rule, what appear there are differentials of the new coordinates.

@ameg but this “equation” is just the definition of the metric tensor. It is not derived from anywhere, it is just a definition (in my book at least), and this mathematical definition uses $d\theta$ in the previous sense (which indeed corresponds to the differential of $\theta$ if you look at $\theta$ as a function of $t,r,\theta,\phi$ returning just $\theta$). Am I being unclear ?

You have two 1-forms $d\theta$ and $d\phi$. You are following a path $\gamma$ on which the restriction of those forms vanish (pedantic notations: $\gamma^* d\theta = \gamma^* d\phi = 0$). As an analogy: the one form $dx - dy$ on $\Bbb R^2$ vanishes along the diagonal $\gamma(t) = (t,t)$.

@Didier hum, I like your answer, I think I’m getting closer to the understanding. Nonetheless, I am not sure I see why the one form you mention vanishes on the diagonal. Indeed, $\gamma^*(dx-dy)(t)=(dx-dy)((t,t))=d_{(t,t)}x-d_{(t,t)}y:=(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2\mapsto a-b$. No ?

@Maxime Forgetting that $\gamma$ is parametrized, and only looking as the diagonal as a submanifold of the plane, can you identify the tangent space of that diagonal at a point as a subspace of the tangent space of $\Bbb R^2$ at that same point? If so, waht can you say about the restriction of $dx - dy$, seen as a linear form, to this subspace?

@Didier Oh yes, of course ! I forgot to restrict the differentials to the tangent space ! In that case,  $(dx-dy)((t,t)):=(a,a)\in\mathbb R (1,1)\mapsto a-a=0$ Many thanks !

As @Didier pointed out, it is all a matter of looking at the object through the right lenses !
What made me confused is the fact that I wasn’t restrincting a 1-form to a submanifold, but rather doing a strange operation. I am not familiar with the theory of manifolds and differential forms on them, which lead to my confusion.
I was thinking that restricting the differential form $d\theta$ to a submanifold N meant to consider $d\theta_{|N}:p\in N\mapsto (d_p\theta:q\in\mathbb R^4\mapsto d_p\theta(q))$. But this vision isn’t correct and was inherited from the usual differential calculus in $\mathbb R^n$ where we do not care about the notion of tangent space when considering differentials. But for general manifolds, forms are defined on the (co)tangent bundle, and a restriction to a submanifold means a restriction to the (co)tangent bundle of the submanifold (the difference being that the tangent spaces at each point of the submanifold are not necessarily the same as the ones of the manifold).
